# Accidentally deleted icons in /usr/share, how do I get them back?

Tags: icons

okay, so tyeing to type "icons" in the /usr/share/ directory, hit the delete key as root, now my icons are gone, all of them, the options for play in totem or the ones on the desktop....all of them, any help?

Answer (score 12):

I like Bash porn so I wrote you a present:

```
for p in `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii  [^\ ]+/ {print $2}'`; do
    if [[ $(dpkg -L $p | grep /usr/share/icons/) ]]; then
        echo $p;
    fi;
done
```

That echos out all the installed packages that had files in `/usr/share/icons/`. If that works for you (it does for me) you can replace the echo statement with:

```
        sudo apt-get --reinstall install $p
```

It's going to use a lot of bandwidth and whatever you do, don't interrupt it, but it should get you all your packaged icons back.

Of course you can reverse that logic so you use something like this:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall -s install $(for p in `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii  [^\ ]+/ {print $2}'`; do if [[ $(dpkg -L $p | grep /usr/share/icons/) ]]; then echo $p; fi; done)
```

The `-s` in there means simulation mode. That command won't actually do anything unless you remove the `-s`, it'll just show you what it would do. I'd probably recommend that before you jump in.

---

As Andrea points out `dpkg -S` can do all this on its own. Plus it's *much* quicker.

```
sudo apt-get -s --reinstall  install `dpkg -S /usr/share/icons/ | sed 's/,//g; s/\:.*$//'`
```

Comment: Wow. Lots of awesome stuff in there.. I'll be studying that script carefully!

Comment: You can use `dpkg -S /usr/share/icons/` instead of the for loop ;-)

Comment: @Oli Very nice(/clever/inteligent) loop. well done.

Comment: I did the same thing and solved it using Andrea's solution and it worked fantastically as well as quickly. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do something like:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $package
```

You will need to replace `$package` with a list of package names, for every single package which had files under that path. That is quite a lot of packages, especially if you have any non-default packages installed.

Something like this might be a good start for you:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall aisleriot alacarte apport aptdaemon-data brasero-common \
bzr-gtk cabextract checkbox dmz-cursor-theme eog evince-common evolution-common \
file-roller gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-applets-data gnome-bluetooth \
gnome-control-center-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-icon-theme \
gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-media gnome-nettool \
gnome-online-accounts gnome-panel-data gnome-power-manager gnome-session-common \
gnome-settings-daemon gnome-system-log gnome-system-tools gnome-themes-standard \
gwibber hicolor-icon-theme human-icon-theme human-theme humanity-icon-theme ibus \
jockey-common libgweather-common liblaunchpad-integration-common libpeas-common \
libreoffice-common nautilus-data network-manager-gnome onboard openjdk-7-jre \
rhythmbox-data seahorse software-center software-properties-gtk synaptic \
totem-common transmission-common ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-mono ubuntuone-client \
ubuntuone-installer unity-asset-pool update-manager update-notifier usb-creator-gtk \
xcursor-themes
```

Answer (score 0):

oh :))

first of all :: don't do this again :)

now, depending on which icons you had, you should reinstall them back via synaptic, console, or USC (ubuntu software center), as was mentioned by 2 other answers

if icons were from default themes, them simply reinstall this
**gnome-icon-theme**

ex. command from *dobey* will look like this

```
apt-get install --reinstall gnome-icon-theme
```