# /usr/share/icons deleted

Tags: icons

I have accidentally deleted all the files in my `/usr/share/icons` directory by using a wrong command. Do you know a solution to restore the files?

Comment: At least tell us the command you used. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/335297/kind-of-messed-up-usr-share-icons seems similar.

Comment: "supprimed" is not a word.  What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I mean that I have deleted all my icons by using sudo rm -R /usr/share/icons/. Thanks Rinzwind, your solution worked for me!

Comment: @Rinzwind why a dupe?

Comment: I never marked it dupe @Braiam :=) I said similar

Answer (score 2):

The command `dpkg -S /usr/share/icons/` should show you what package you need to reinstall in order to restore your icons:

```
➜  ~  dpkg -S /usr/share/icons/ 
gnome-icon-theme-extras, gimp-data, gnome-colors-common, gnome-brave-icon-theme, alacarte, gnome-online-accounts, smplayer, eog, libreoffice-common, gcr, baobab, gnome-system-log, evince-common, emacs24-common, hicolor-icon-theme, libpeas-common, byobu, desktop-base, icedtea-netx-common, gnome-icon-theme, empathy-common, gnome-session-common, gnome-control-center-data, gnome-settings-daemon, gnome-power-manager, gnome-media, shotwell-common, cabextract, gnome-panel-data, libgweather-common, gnome-disk-utility, imagemagick, gdm3, openjdk-7-jre:i386, gnome-themes-standard-data, gnome-user-share, gparted, rygel, vinagre, cheese-common, gnome-bluetooth, iceweasel, file-roller, xchat, rhythmbox-data, seahorse, deluge-gtk, gnome-packagekit-data, gnome-icon-theme-symbolic, brasero-common, gnome-tweak-tool, aisleriot, gnome-accessibility-themes, ettercap-graphical, pidgin-data, zim, chromium, gconf-editor, dconf-editor, ibus, steam, gbrainy, network-manager-gnome, flashplugin-nonfree, synaptic, geary, tracker-gui, xterm, freeciv-data, gnome-applets-data, gsmartcontrol, wireshark-common, wireshark, upnp-router-control, ppstream, ibus-anthy: /usr/share/icons
```

Is not an easy task, but it should leave you in the good path. You can reinstall using:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall package
```

Comment: One-liner for all package reinstall may be used too - `sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/share/icons | sed -e 's#,##g' | sed "s|: /usr/share/icons||")` .