# How to reinstall or download the original Ubuntu icons folder?

Tags: icons

I erased some of the icon folders I was not using to free up some space. As a result, it seems that I ended up erasing some predefined icons and other important files.  So even when I use an icon theme that has replacements for most of the original icons, they are still missing.

I was wondering if there is any place where I can download the original Ubuntu installation icons folder and paste it on my system to fix this.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Just execute:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall yaru-theme-icon
```

This will download the icons and place them into the correct folder under `/usr/share/icons/Yaru`.

Comment: It's still not it. I must have erased some other type of configuration folders in the way. I'm still missing icons, and the differ according to the icon theme I choose. With Yaru they're mostly... all white?

Comment: I found this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/113225/accidentally-deleted-icons-in-usr-share-how-do-i-get-them-back

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall all files in `/usr/share` by using command below:

```
apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/share/ | sed 's/,//g' | sed 's/: \/usr\/share//g')
```

where:

- `dpkg -S /usr/share/` shows the list of comma-separated packages;
- `sed 's/,//g'` - removes commas;
- `sed 's/: \/usr\/share//g'` - removes `: /usr/share` in the end.

And then reboot.

Please do not change files which are controlled by APT again!
Use special user's folders like `~/.local/share/icons/` and system-wide like `/usr/local/share/icons/`.